# Using ADO code to add a UDF to Pervasive database

Tags: sql, delphi, ado, pervasive

I have a CREATE FUNCTION statement in a text file.
I need to add this function to a Pervasive database (v13 minimum) at runtime using ADO and the OLEDB provider.
I could use ODBC if that is what it takes.

I have set up an ADOCommand object and an ADOQuery object.
I drop the function if it exists like so:

```
cmd.CommandText := format('DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS %s', [GetFunctionName(sl.Text)]);  // sl is a StringList containing the content of the file
cmd.Execute;
```

Then I try to execute the CREATE FUNCTION text like so:

```
qry.SQL.Text := sl.Text;  // sl is a StringList containing the content of the file 
qry.Prepared := true;
qry.Parameters.Clear;
qry.ExecSQL;
{  or this way
cmd.CommandText := sl.Text;  // sl is a StringList containing the content of the file
cmd.Parameters.Clear;
cmd.Execute;
}
```

I get this error using either a Command or Query to execute the text:
[image]

I think this is because variables in PSQL are identified by a leading ":" and ADO thinks they are parameter placeholders.
Here is a snippet from my CREATE FUNCTION text as an example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FormatDate(:sDate char(8))
--Version 2
--Comment Convert Sympac date string to DD/MM/YYYY
--Group Conversion
RETURNS char(10)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE :dd char(2)
DECLARE :mm char(2)
DECLARE :yyyy char(4)
```

How can I run my CREATE FUNCTION text using ADO?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You were close. It is Delphi itself that in supporting named parameters in SQL using the :NAME syntax that does the conversion to ? syntax. You need to turn this off when it gets in the way.

Turn off ParamCheck.

```
cmd.Parameters.Clear;
cmd.ParamCheck := false;
cmd.CommandText := sl.Text;  
cmd.Execute;
```

The Delphi help for ParamCheck mentions this:

> This property is useful for data definition language (DDL) statements
> that contain parameters as part of the DDL statement and that are not
> parameters for the ADO command component. For example, the DDL
> statement to create a stored procedure may contain parameter
> statements that are part of the stored procedure. Set ParamCheck to
> false to prevent these parameters from being mistaken for parameters
> of the ADO command component executing the DDL statement.